# Best way to positionning Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js

Not considering fragments, I'm wondering if it is better to position a child from its inner css scope or from the parent.

In the example below, is it better to do `margin-left: auto;` on the parent side or on the child side (both work)

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div class="childClassFromItself">
      Hi from the child
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
})
```

```css
#demo {
  display: flex;
}

.childClassFromParent {
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
}

.childClassFromItself {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  {{ message }}
  <Child class="childClassFromParent"/>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

So is one way is better than the other or is it too specific from one component usage to another ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margin in 99% of cases should be applied by **the parent** to the child.

You don't really know where you'll use Child. Somemetimes you'll need a 10px margin, and then the designer turns the world upside down on some new mobile layout and the margin needs to be 2px.

If you used Child eg. in 10 places in your app and it has a 10px margin inside itself, you'll groan about how now you need to add some weird prop to it like "isSmallMargin" to change its margin to accomodate the new 2px margin.

On the other hand, if the margin is determined by the parent, you are free to modify the margin however you like in the different parents of Child throughout the app.

But since you're talking about styles in general, not just margin...

As a rule of thumb:

1. If the style concerns layout (flex, grid), spacing (margin), of the Child's root element it should be in the parent
2. If the style concerns the child itself - color, font-size, layout of other elements INSIDE the child - it should be in Child itself

Try to avoid overriding inner CSS properties from outside the component too:

```html
<!-- Don't do this! -->
<template>
  <div>
    <Child class="ugly-override">
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.ugly-override > .childClassFromItself {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That seems logic thank you, the only disturbing point is that we need to add a class to every component we need to layout

Comment: Not really. In your parent you can do something like .parent > * { margin-left: 10px } so "for every direct child of parent, add a margin-left: 10px to that chid"

Comment: It can be a bit tricky if it's a complex html and you use a lot of components don't you think ? But anyway yes it is a good solution